# Make a form and fetch values for non-input fields with Angular Material

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

I have a Angular Material form with a dropdown menu, from which a customer can select a value.

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>CHOOSE ACCOUNT</mat-label>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let account of accounts" [value]="account.name">{{account.name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

At the same time, I follow this guide: https://angular.io/start/forms, which guides you to implement `formControlName`. I want to apply this to `<mat-option>`, so that I can fetch the chosen value from the dropdown.
I have implemented all of the steps in the guide, but it seems like `formControlName` doesnt work very well with `<mat-option>`.

So in short: How do I make a dropdown with Angular Material (done above), **and be able to fetch the chosen value from a dropdown**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *formControlName* works fine with a mat-select. You have to put the 'formControlName' property in the mat-select and not in the mat-option.

```
<mat-select formControlName="myFormControl">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let account of accounts" [value]="account.name">{{account.name}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: Interesting, I think I already tried that. I will report back tomorrow, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use (onSelectionChange) to achieve this.

Simply use it on mat-option tag and handle form value change in custom function

component.html

```
<mat-option 
  *ngFor="let account of accounts"
  [value]="account.name"
  (onSelectionChange)="selected($event)"
>{{account.name}}</mat-option>
```

component.ts

```
selected(event) {
 this.myForm.controls.nameOfValueToBeChanged.setValue([event.value]);
 // or do whatever you want with event.value
}
```

Comment: It didn't recognize the hashtag (#event) in selected parameter in component.html, so i didnt get it to work with this. thanks for the help!

Comment: It should be: $event

Comment: @thesystem. It was typo that is fixed. Try it now.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the update - I don't have access to the code right now, but will report back tomorrow

Comment: @Adam Thank you very much for the help. In component.ts, I initialize some variables only inside the constructor (see step 4 of this guide with formbuilder: https://angular.io/start/forms), so I cant access the `valueToBeChanged` within `selected(event)`. I really appreciate it though

Answer (score 1):

**Uncorrect see below for better way**

You might simply hook up a [(NgModel)] which links the selects value to the Value of your chosen FormControl, which itself just get created in your .ts-file.
Something like:

comp.ts

```
/.../    
ngOnInit(){
      this.form.registerControl('OptionsControl', this.formbuilder.control());
      this.optionsControl = this.form.get('OptionsControl');
/../
```

comp.html

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="optionsControl.value">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let account of accounts" [value]="account.name">{{account.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**___EDIT___**

The value attribute of a formcontrol is now readonly and can therefore not be directly assigned that way. Instead the selections should be chosen as a listened event like below:

```
 <mat-select placeholder="Select your choice">
    <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="optionsControl.setValue(account)" *ngFor="let account of accounts"
                [value]="account.name">{{account.name}}
   </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

Thanks to @Adam to mention this solution first, i simply felt the need to correct my mistakes here.

Comment: When I try to `console.log(this.optionsControl)` upon form submission, it states `Object object` so it seems as if it doesn't receive the right data?

Comment: oh yeah I am seeing the problem. Value is a readonly field in the current versions.
In that case i would recommend the answer of @Adam